# How can several Google users share their photos from one place?

Tags: google-workspace, photo-sharing, google-plus-photos

I take pictures of my kids with my phone, and the phone auto-uploads them to Google+ so I can share them. My wife also takes pictures with her phone, but her photos can't go into the same destination because she has her own Google account (obviously). This is tedious.

How can we have her photos and mine go into the same destination? Is there something like a shared album, or a way to have her phone send her photos into my account (while still keeping her phone running her own account!)?

What we currently do is either e-mail individual photos from her phone to me, or download photos from her phone onto my PC. This is cumbersome and time-consuming.

Comment: Any news on this? Have you considered using other services which grab from google, such as EntourageBox?

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility that comes to mind is to share a folder in Google Drive. Then both of you could turn on the Google+ Photos feature to display each such folder as an album. Then it's just a question of moving/copying your Auto-Backup'd photos to that album (folder).

[Google+ Help: View photos stored in your Google Drive](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3259546)

> 1. Open [Google+](https://plus.google.com/). Place your cursor in the top left corner for the Google+ main menu.
> 2. Click **Settings**.
> 3. In the **Photos** section, check the box next to **Show Drive photos in your photo library**. To stop showing your Google Drive photos, uncheck the box. After you enable the feature, folders containing JPG, GIF, WebP, RAW or video files will be viewable from your [Google+ photo library](https://plus.google.com/photos) and each Drive folder will become a different album marked with the [image: Google Drive icon] Google Drive icon. Only you will be able to see them in your library until you choose to share them.

Comment: Arrh, _so close_ and yet so far away: _"This feature is not available for Google Apps accounts."_ and yes, I use Google Apps with my family name as the domain name.

Answer (score 2):

I heard a rumor about shared photo albums being developed in the future, but can't find where I saw that.

Staying in the Googleverse, the only thing I know of that will do something like this is [Google+ Events](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/events/). If you RSVP to an event and turn on the feature when the event comes up, then all the photos you take (until the end of the event) are uploaded to the event. This is true of all attendees, and offers a chronological record of photos for the event shared with all attendees.

Comment: Events is the only solution I could think of, but for that to be practical I would have to have a single, year-long event, and that seems like a rather dirty workaround.

Comment: Or repeating events every day, if you take as many photos of your children as my wife did when they were tots. But, yeah, it's not a great solution.

Comment: Because I really use that "Googleverse" and have my calendar on my phone's default screen, having a permanent dummy calendar entry would drive me nuts :-) Still, have an upvote for the simple workaround.

Answer (score -1):

The limitation here is not technology, I think, it's how to manage changes.

Say you and your wife divorce.   Even with shared albums, Google will know which of you uploaded each photo, so could easily enough let you "unshare" permissions and only see photos that you uploaded.   But what if there's a court-order saying that she gets access to all the family photos.   (Don't laugh - it happens with photo albums in real life!).    Somehow Google will be expected to facilitate this.

There are lots of similar scenarios:   I work for a company, and upload photos using my G+ account.    I leave - but because the photos were taken on work time, they should own the photos, not me.

Headaches all around.  I'm not holding my breath for a solution anytime soon.

Comment: While this is useful information, I don't see how it answers the question.

Comment: The "answer" is simply not to expect any way to do this anytime soon.